# Impossible dygraphs exportation on MAC

Tags: r, macos, export, rstudio, dygraphs

I have to use Dygraphs package in Rstudio for my master internship on my mac but I think it don't work correctly... I can't export my dygraphs on my computer !

I tried to export it with the "export" tab in dygraphs viewer but nothing happened (no file created and no error message). I also tried to export it by using `pdf('test.pdf')` but the created pdf file (test.pdf) is empty...

I tried to re-install R, Rstudio, Xcode and Command Line Tool but the problem persists...
I tried to use dygraphs package on several computers (Windows and MAC) and it seemed to work perfectly on Windows OS but not on MAC.

Does someone know how to fix this issue ?

Thx :)

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

here is a little reproductible example. When I tried to export `graph` with the "export" button of the viewer, no file was created...

`library(zoo)`

`library(xts)`

`library(dygraphs)`

`# Creation of a time-based data serie (Normally, I use .dat files)`

`TIMESTAMP <- seq(as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2017-02-28 23:00:00"), 60*60) # Time serie`

`values <- seq(1, length(TIMESTAMP), 1) # Values I want to plot with Dygraphs`

`values <- xts(x = values, order.by = TIMESTAMP)`

`graph <- dygraph(values)`